# weird behaviour with nested loops in bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, nested, io-redirection

I'd like to know why this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
seq 1 3 > foo
COUNT=0
while read VAR1; do
    while read VAR2; do
        let COUNT++
        echo -n $COUNT
    done < foo
done < foo
```

outputs: `123456789`

while this other bash script, that (AFAIK) should do the exact same thing

```
#!/bin/bash

seq 1 3 > foo

COUNT=0
while read VAR1; do
    cat foo | while read VAR2; do
        let COUNT++
        echo $COUNT
    done
done < foo
```

outputs: `123123123`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the pipeline runs in a subshell. Therefore, changes to the COUNT variable do not persist after the end of the inner loop in the second case.

Answer (score 3):

Using `|` invoke a subshell and hence your variable holds no value in it.

A quick look at the debug log will explain the scenario. Run both script as `bash -x scriptname` and you should answer yourself.

Comment: subshells mantain the variables of the parent shell with the same value though. it's not true they hold no value in it.

Comment: @blue Correct. I didn't mean to write that. I should have said, the increments made to the variable in the inner loop does not hold true after the loop has completed.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the inner loop is in a pipeline. Therefore, it is executed in a subshell, so changes to the variable COUNT are local to the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cat foo | ...` looks suspicious to me. Basically, I think you're getting the file `foo` catted again and again without going in to the `VAR2` `while` loop.

Comment: this does work though: `cat foo | while read VAR; do echo $VAR; done`